# MongoDB:index GeoHaystack something wrong with geoSearch example

Tags: mongodb

I have an "collection" named "places" with this structure

```
{
     _id : 100, pos: { lng : 126.9, lat : 35.2 } , type : "restaurant"
}
{ 
    _id : 200, pos: { lng : 127.5, lat : 36.1 } , type : "restaurant"}
{ 
    _id : 300, pos: { lng : 128.0, lat : 36.7 } , type : "national park"
 }
```

I execute runCommand like this

```
db.runCommand( { geoSearch : "places" ,
             search : { type: "restaurant" } ,
             near : [120, 40] ,
             maxDistance : 10 } )
```

And it shows me 3 results when it must show 2 results because the _id 300 have type national park.

Or i'm wrong. Does the searches with index type "GeoHaystack" is done with another way?.

If the response could be in simple english or spanish i'll aprecite it.

<--More information-->

I explain this is very strange. If i create the collection places with field type. Runs correctly dbCommand it returns 2 results as user Gabe says. But,i don't know why,if i create collection changing field "type "for "tipo" and "runCommand" as "tipo":"restaurant" it returns 3 records. Is very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the same data, then ran the haystack index (below), then the `db.runCommand` and got an expected 2 results.

You may have added an extra record on insert. Simply run `db.places.find({})` and see how many total records are in the collection.

The index used was `db.places.ensureIndex( { pos : "geoHaystack", type : 1 } , { bucketSize : 1 } )`

Comment: Thanks Gabe. It's true with "type" runCommand runs correctly but if the field has the name "tipo" it runs incorrectly. Is very strange.

Comment: hmm. perhaps the spanish localization has a bug with the 'tipo' (type) reserved word!

Comment: Thanks another time.  Maybe I 'll have to try it but nowaday i dont' have anything with MongoDB.